# mysql multiple count and group values in a same field

Tags: mysql, sql

I was looking around but couldn't find an answer
I need a query that return 2 groups of values as field names based on values in a same field

example I have a table

```
NAME, VALUE
name1, 2
name1, 2
name1, 3
name1, 4
name2, 2
name2, 2
name2, 3
name2, 4
```

now I want to count and group values 2 and 3 in one group and values 4 in another group so my result would look like this

```
NAME, GRP1_COUNT, GRP2_COUNT
name1, 3, 1
name2, 3, 1
```

I tried the `JOIN` and `UNION` without much luck
any help appreciated

Comment: Search for "mysql rows to columns" and "mysql pivot"

Answer (score 15):

MySQL does not have a *pivot* function so you will have to transform the data using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression. For this type of calculation you will use either `COUNT` or `SUM`:

```
select name,
  sum(case when value in (2,3) then 1 else 0 end) GRP1_COUNT,
  sum(case when value = 4 then 1 else 0 end) GRP2_COUNT
from yourtable
group by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c505a/1)

`COUNT` version:

```
select name,
  count(case when value in (2,3) then VALUE end) GRP1_COUNT,
  count(case when value = 4 then VALUE end) GRP2_COUNT
from yourtable
group by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c505a/2)

Comment: Is there any neater way? Not including the hardcorded value.

Comment: @Deckard yes you can use a prepared statement to execute dynamic sql

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
SELECT
name,
sum(case when value=2 or value=3 then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when value=4 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not so hard to do when posting a code only answer. Not that this answer isn't upvote worthy, but the comparison is just not fair

Comment: @Lamak . . . when I wrote that comment, both answers had just the code.  The other answer has been modified and much improved with explanation (as is usually the case for bluefeet).

Comment: i'm just happy that my first ever answer on this site (or any site like this) has (had) the exact same code with an expert!

Comment: Is there any neater way? Not including the hardcorded value.